# Проверка наличие картинки | PHP

Tags: php7

Код в WP, использую плагин ACF.

Условие:
Есть картинка (баннер) и слайдер. Они делят между собой одно место на сайте. Т.е. если есть картинка, - слайдер не показывается, а если нет картинки - слайдер показывается.

Код:

```php
  <?php $banner = get_field('banner_stock');
            if (isset($banner)) { ?>
    <img class="offer-center__banner" src="<?php echo $banner['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['alt']; ?>" />
    <?php } else { ?>

    <!-- Advantages - offer-center__slider -->
    <div class="offer-center__slider df">
      <!-- advantage №1 -->
      <a href="advantages" class="offer-center__slider_item">
        <?php $image = get_field('advantage_1_img'); ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
        <p>
          <?php the_field('advantage_1_txt'); ?>
        </p>
      </a>
      <!-- advantage №2 -->
      <a href="advantages" class="offer-center__slider_item">
        <?php $image = get_field('advantage_2_img'); ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
        <p>
          <?php the_field('advantage_2_txt'); ?>
        </p>
      </a>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

В данном случаи выполняется только первое условие - картинка (баннер) показывается, но как только убираешь из базы WP слайдер не хочет показываться. Можете подсказать как правильно написать код, чтобы исполнялось 2-е условие - когда картинке в базе нет и показывается слайдер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не уверен, но попробуйте заменить:

> `if (isset($banner))`

на:

> `if (!empty($banner))`

во второй строчке.

[isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php), проверяет переменную на существование, а так как она определена, всегда вернётся **true** (если там будет пустая строка, а не **null**). В тоже время [empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php), также проверяет на существование, но дополнительно проверяет и на пустоту.

Либо поле в БД должно быть явно **NULL**, а не пустой строкой. Тогда условие выполнится!

Чтобы убедится что возвращается когда нет баннера, сделайте:

> var_dump($banner);

И посмотрите что у Вас там, если **string**, тогда моё предположение верно...

Comment: Рабочий ответ. [Эта функция возвращает false.](http://hookr.io/functions/get_field/)

Comment: Да, все правильно - нужно было поменять значение на - if (!empty($banner)). В моем случае нужно было почистить еще кеш браузера, сразу не понял, что получилось! Спасибо Вадиму!

Comment: @DenisBolotnikov, Пожалуйста, если считаете вопрос закрытым, отметьте ответ галочкой.